# Delaying live video streams

Tags: vlc-media-player, streaming, delay

I'm currently watching two live video streams (from two different cameras) but one of them is about 16 seconds ahead of the other. Is there any way I can get the stream that's ahead to cache and delay for about 16 seconds to bring them both into video sync? I don't care about audio sync since I'm muting one of the streams anyway.

I'm currently watching them using VLC, but any other software would be fine if I can't do this with VLC.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not muting the stream which needs to be delayed, you can try delaying the video from the one that needs to be 16 seconds delayed by using the manual audio sync capability of VLC.  You can delay the video by pressing Ctrl+K which should "speed up" the sound by delaying the video.  Unfortunately it only does this 50ms at a time and you need to delay by 16000ms (Audio delay -16000ms) Luckily if you hold the key down it will keep counting up.  It only took me about a minute to delay that much.